# How to override auth/local/register endpoint validations in Strapi Framework?

Tags: strapi

I am new to Strapi framework (started learning today itself) and My front-end has login with Instagram only. So no need to remove email and password validation for the  http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register endpoint.

I have removed validation from .chache/admin/containers/AuthPage/forms.js, but it doesn't get affected.

Where do I making mistake? I have searched for the answer but didn't get it.

Comment: Did you rebuilt the admin panel by running 'yarn build' after your update.

Comment: @JimLAURIE: Yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution.

I copied `config` and `controllers` folder from `node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions` into `extensions/users-permissions` and made changes in `controllers/Auth.js` and it worked .

Comment: @YordanGeorgiev the link to the documentation is broken!

Comment: I think this won't work in v4